# When using ActiveRecord STI, how do I (and should I?) validate for inclusion in subclasses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sti

I'm currently using single table inheritance in the following model for roles:

```rb
# app/models/role.rb
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
end

class Observer < Role; end
class Manager < Role; end
class Owner < Role; end
```

I tried adding a constant to check for inclusion at the top of the class:

```rb
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  ROLE = subclasses.map(&:name)

  # and

  validates :type, inclusion: { in: ROLE }

  # ...
end
```

But this gets me `ROLE # => []`, as the subclasses are loaded after its build.

I currently got it to work by using a custom validation method with AR:

```rb
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  validate :subclass_check

  # ...

  private

  def subclass_check
    return true if Role.subclasses.map(&:name).include?(type)
    errors.add(:type, "#{type} is not a type of Role")
  end
end
```

But I still get the feeling that I'm either doing something janky, reinventing the wheel, or both.

So, how do I (and should I?) validate for inclusion in subclasses on update?

Comment: You're testing Rails or Ruby itself at this point, no? What else could it be?

Comment: The reason why I might need the validation is because you can instantiate a valid role:
`role = Role.new(type: 'Observer')`
And then update it with `role.update(type: 'Necromancer')`, which then persists and invalid object.

All further calls to instantiate the record from the DB then return:
`ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'Necromancer'.`

Comment: When I've used STI, which is very rarely, the type has been controlled, and the system wasn't abused by creating instances of the parent class. If the system is built in such a way that the parent class is exposed like this, validation is a good idea (or just attempt to instantiate and rescue).

Comment: @Broquel I know this question is a few years old but has your custom validation still been the best way to go about making sure the parent class type attribute is the subclasses/descendants?